# not able to call json file in powershell

Tags: powershell

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName cal-1274-8 -Name storage-deployment -TemplateFile .\template.json

Getting below error while executing above script. Please help

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot find path
'C:\Users\student\template.json' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

- New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName cal-1274-8 -Name sto ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation 
  .NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
  ```

Comment: May sound stupid, but have you checked whether the file is actually found in the location named by the error message?

Comment: Avoid problems like that and use full path and file names